Problem unpacking/assembling Bambulab P1S
I bought a BambuLab P1S Printer and tried to assemble it. Beside some other problems, I am still in the unpacking process and don't know how to extract the foam from the printer because the heat-bed is not moving and I don't want to destroy it
I add a foto of the problem

According to the Quick Start Guide for P1P, the section Printer Binding mentions the following:


Follow the instructions on the screen to complete the initial calibration.
It is normal to have vibration and noise during the calibration process.
DO NOT remove the protective foam from beneath the hot bed until after the initial calibration is complete.



While not extremely clear, I would assume that once the calibration is done you can then move the build plate up and remove the foam.
In the Unboxing P1P, the instructions in Step 10: Complete the Initialization, self-test, and upgrade the firmware:

The self-test process begins after you click the OK button.
Remove the fixed foam under the heatbed when the self-test is finished.

Again, you can then move the build plate up and remove the foam.

I found out: when all things are prepared, then the printer should be power on. When it starts, the plate will be raised and the foam can be taken out
This wasn't written in the documentation, only in a YouTube video
